# Identify a specific frame number of a video file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, frame

I have a video file from which I've extracted a specific frame to analyze. However, I want to know what the frame number of this frame is.
I can't seem to find anything. I've had a look at `ffmpeg showinfo`, but that doesn't seem to work.
I've also looked into `exifread`, which produced information about the frame - except for the frame number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you the one extracting the frame? If so, what command?

Comment: no, so someone else has extracted the frame. I jus want to know what frame number the frame is. Is that information embedded in the frame?

Comment: If you have just a JPG/PNG, no.Not unless it's already saved. You'll have to do a frame comparison to id it.

Comment: Frames use time stamps from the packets they get decoded from, AVFrame->pkt_pts (packet presentation time stamp), not frame numbers. The pts values are based on the streams 'pkt_timebase' to which with a bit of calculation you should be able to estimate the frame number.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a frame number. You can count frames from the start of the video, but the frame itself does not record that information. If you extract a frame to make a stand alone image, its frames number is now 1 of 1